# strlcpy in terms of strncpy on platforms that don't have strlcpy

Tags: c, arrays, string, copy, strncpy

I know, `strlcpy` is safer than `strncpy` while copying from source to destination character arrays where we want destination to be null terminated,
Is the following wrapper ok?

```
size_t strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t size) {
  if (size != 0) {
    int maxSize = size - 1;
    int currSize = -1;
    while ((++currSize < maxSize) && (*dst++ = *src++));
    *dst = 0;
    return currSize;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Please comment.

Answer (score 0):

The check for `size` to be above zero is misleading, because `size_t` is unsigned. A more readable check is `if (size != 0) ...`

Another problem is that `strncpy` pads its destination with zeros up to `s`, which `strlcpy` does not do. If you would like to match the behavior of `strlcpy`, write your own implementation on systems where it is not available, rather than relying on `strncpy`.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementations is very fast, but with two quirks:

- One quirk is that your function writes two NUL-characters instead of one when there is enough space.
- Another quirk is the return value which doesn't indicate issues.

Apart from these quircks, your version is functionally equivalent to `strxcpy()` by [attractivechaos](https://github.com/attractivechaos/strxcpy). However, your code is 30-100% faster depending on which machine I use. Good job in that respect!

Regarding the return value, here are the differences I observe:

- the [original](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strlcpy) `strlcpy` returns length of `src`:

  - *cons:* **unsafe**, **unnecessarily slow**
  - *pros:* `strlcpy(d,s,n)` is equivalent to `snprintf(d,n,"%s",s)`
- [strxcpy](https://github.com/attractivechaos/strxcpy) by attractivechaos returns number of bytes written:

  - *pros:* return value doesn't clearly indicate an issue when src is too long
  - *cons:* deviates from strlcpy in return value
- your function returns length of the string length written:

  - *cons:*

    - return value doesn't clearly indicate an issue when src is too long
    - return value doesn't indicate whether NUL-character was written or not
  - *pros:* more in line with the original strlcpy.

In my preferred implementation all the mentioned functional disadvantages are fixed:

```
ssize_t safe_strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t size)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return -1;

    size_t ret = strnlen(src, size);
    size_t len = (ret >= size) ? size - 1 : ret;
    memcpy(dst, src, len);
    dst[len] = '\0';
    return ret;
}
```

It returns `size` when `src` was too long and didn't fit entirely; -1 if `size` is zero; otherwise - string length written. So, when everything is OK, the return value is still in line with strlcpy. And it's based on [Git's implementation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/compat/strlcpy.c) of the original strlcpy.